# How to upload RDF code to fuseki server using Java?

Tags: java, rdf, fuseki

I wrote a function that convert data to RDF and I need to upload this RDF to the fuseki server.

I tried to implement the code from [here](http://pinesong.ghost.io/how-to-upload-rdf-file-to-jena-fuseki-server-using-java-code/) as follows

```
public class GenerateRDF {
      public void setRDF(String[] personalData ) {
        String serviceURI = "http://localhost:3030/Date";
        DatasetAccessorFactory factory = null;
        DatasetAccessor accessor;
        accessor = factory.createHTTP(serviceURI);

        String name = personalData[0];
        String nationality = personalData[1];
        String date = personalData[2];
        String address = personalData[3];
        String mobile = personalData[4];
        String email = personalData[5];
        String website = personalData[6];
        String profesional = personalData[7];
        String education = personalData[8];
        String communication = personalData[9];
        String digital = personalData[10];
        String professional = personalData[11];
        String management = personalData[12];
        String certifications = personalData[13];

        InputStream in = null;
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        Resource node = model.createResource(personURI)
             .addProperty(FOAF.name, name)
             .addProperty(FOAF.member, nationality)
             .addProperty(FOAF.birthday, date)
             .addProperty(FOAF.homepage, address)
             .addProperty(FOAF.phone, mobile)
             .addProperty(FOAF.yahooChatID, email)
             .addProperty(FOAF.weblog, website)
             .addProperty(FOAF.plan, profesional)
             .addProperty(FOAF.knows, education)
             .addProperty(FOAF.depiction, communication)
             .addProperty(FOAF.interest, digital)
             .addProperty(FOAF.publications, professional)
             .addProperty(FOAF.maker, management)
             .addProperty(FOAF.made, certifications);
        String base = "http://test-projects.com/";
        model.read(in, base, "RDF/XML");
        accessor.putModel(model);
        model.write(System.out);
    }
}
```

Which returns the following Exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.readAndBuffer(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDocumentEntity(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:151)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.ARP.load(ARP.java:119)
>       at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangRDFXML.parse(LangRDFXML.java:142)
>       at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTFactoryImpl$1.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:142)
>       at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:760)
>       at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:258)
>       at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:244)
>       at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT.read(RDFReaderRIOT.java:69)
>       at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:274)
>       at GenerateRDF.setRDF(GenerateRDF.java:59)
>       at PersonalInfo$2.actionPerformed(PersonalInfo.java:251)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Is there a way to fix this error? I'm open to solutions...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look here : https://hub.docker.com/r/stain/jena-fuseki/

There is a part on data loading that can guide you.

More specifically, load.sh and tdbloader that can be found here : https://github.com/stain/jena-docker/tree/master/jena-fuseki

I'm a bit puzzled by your question as you mention "upload a file to fuseki" in the tittle but your code does not refer to any file...

Comment: You are right, sorry! There is no file, I need to upload RDF code to the Fuseki server.